# Showing that $U(f,R) = U(f,P) + U(f,Q)$ where $R = P \cup Q$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, riemann-sum, upper-lower-bounds

I have to show that $U(f,R)  = U(f,P) + U(f,Q)$ where $R = P \cup Q$, I found a way where I proved that $U(f,R) - U(f,P) = U(f,Q)$, but it's sort of long and doesn;t translate well to prove the same result but for $R = P_1 \cup P_2 \cup P_3 \cup ... \cup P_n$. Is there a better, more simpler way to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Since $R$ is a refinement of both $P$ and $Q$, the upper sum for $R$ is less than or equal to each of the upper sums for $P$ and $Q$.  Hence, this is not true in general.

For example, if $f$ is positive then

$$0 < U(R,f) \leqslant U(P,f), \,\,\,\,0 < U(R,f) \leqslant U(Q,f), $$

and $U(R,f) < U(P,f) + U(Q,f)$.

An exception where it holds is the trivial case where $f(x)$ is everywhere $0$, and perhaps some contrived partitions when $f(x)$ is not always of the same sign.

Comment: So U(f,R) not always equal to U(f,P)+U(f,Q)?

Comment: No it is not. Upper sums decrease and lower sums increase as the partition gets finer. That is how they converge to the integral when $f$ is Riemann integrable. Try drawing a picture.